# Microsoft Access - Login

Tags: ms-access, authentication

just curious if it is possible to store a label with someones login name.

i would like it so that when a check box is ticked, it will show the username of the person who is logged (checked by "Bob").

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

- In your project, define a public variable `strUserName` and set the value to `strUserName = Environ("Username")` on Form load or from `User` table defined.
- Using the click event of the checkbox set the label caption.

---

```
Public strUsername As String

Private Sub chk1_Click()
    If Me.chk1.Value Then
        Me.lbl_username.Caption = strUsername
    Else
         Me.lbl_username.Caption = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    strUsername = Environ("Username")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Santosh, you helped me before with the login labels. as you have an idea of how my login works. i may i incorporate this into the check box labels.